# executor failed running [/bin/bash -c python /root/docker_fetch.py]: exit code: 1

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, dockerfile, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to create image using Dockerfile. Here is my dockerfile.

```
 FROM us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/training/tf-gpu.2-8:latest
USER root
CMD python --version
COPY *.txt /
COPY ./whl_files/*.whl /
ADD ./train/ /train/
RUN pip install wheel
# RUN pip install ./whl_files/*.whl
RUN pip install torch-1.11.0+cu113-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
RUN pip install torchaudio-0.11.0+cu113-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
RUN pip install torchvision-0.12.0+cu113-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
# RUN pip install whl_files/torchvision-0.12.0+cu113-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl
# RUN pip3 install --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org torch==1.11.0+cu113 torchvision==0.12.0+cu113 torchaudio==0.11.0+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html
# RUN pip3 install --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org torch==1.9.0+cu111 torchvision==0.10.0+cu111 torchaudio==0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
RUN pip3 install --ignore-installed -r requirements.txt --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
COPY *.py /root/
RUN chmod +x /root/docker_fetch.py
RUN python /root/docker_fetch.py

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

I am getting this error:

```
=> [11/12] RUN chmod +x /root/docker_fetch.py                                                                                                                                                                     0.2s
 => ERROR [12/12] RUN python /root/docker_fetch.py                                                                                                                                                                 4.8s
------
 > [12/12] RUN python /root/docker_fetch.py:
#16 4.169 Fetch python libs data
------
```

At last line of Dockerfile, I am getting this error.

Here is `docker_fetch.py`

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForSequenceClassification
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from transformers import XLMRobertaTokenizer, XLMRobertaForMaskedLM

def fetch_sentence_transformer():
    SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2')


def fetch_bert():
    BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
    BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

def fetch_xlmRoberta():
    XLMRobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained("xlm-roberta-large")
    XLMRobertaForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("xlm-roberta-large", return_dict=True,)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Fetch python libs data')
    fetch_bert()
    fetch_xlmRoberta()
    fetch_sentence_transformer()
```

Comment: What is the actual error message? Also are your `pip` and `pip3` the same? `pip` is running while in some lines while `pip3` is running in others. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Its giving SSL Certificate error.